# Spring MVC based RESTfull Web Services authentication using 'Remember Me'

Tags: restful-authentication

I have restful APIs in place. I have used Spring MVC annotations. I have a requirement to authenticate a userid and on authentication create a session and allow the user to call other APIs till session lasts. My question is: Does creation of a session and maintaining it go against the idea of restfulness. If yes, how do I secure my restful API? If I do not secure it, anybody in the network can hit the URL and get the response. Please suggest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed you are right, REST should be stateless, which means keeping a cookie with a session ID goes against the principle. But don't despair, there are solutions.

### Basic

I assume you are using spring-security. The simplest option is to use stateless HTTP Basic authentication for the REST path, and keep the form login for the rest of the site, which is directly supported in spring-security. The security configuration XML would look like this:

```
<!-- for the REST api, the ROLE_API_CONSUMER is a custom role
     I usually use so that not all users are allowed to use the API -->
<security:http pattern="/api/**" auto-config="false" create-session="stateless">
    <security:http-basic />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="ROLE_API_COSUMER" />
</security:http>
<!-- for the other MVC controllers -->
<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:form-login />
</security:http>
<!-- usual stuff to keep track of users -->
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <security:password-encoder ref="encoder" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

This method requires HTTPS to be truly secure, and has the disadvantage that the REST client must store the username and password of the user. If the client is a smartphone, stealing the phone would give access to the credentials of the user in plain text.

### OAuth

[OAuth (either 1.0a or 2)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) is what most modern APIs use and provides an extra level of security. Instead of storing the user's credentials, to access the API the REST client first requests an access permission to the server. In a nutshell, the server then shows the user a "do you approve this client to access the API?"-kind of notice, and if the user approves, the REST client gets a token it can use to authenticate as the user, but without the user's password. If the users's mobile phone is stolen, the thief cannot see any password there, and the access token can be made invalid.

I have no experience setting up OAuth in spring-security, but there is indeed a module for it, check http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/oauth/

I hope to have helped you!